# Converting unix timestamp to datetime in Java

Tags: java, unix-timestamp

I have an Unix timestamp (with microsecond precision) value in 1.514408397505346E9. What is the correct way to convert it to readable date time format?

Is it correct to convert like below?

```
java.util.Date dateTime = new java.util.Date((long) Double.valueOf(unixTimestamp).longValue() * 1000);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
final String reportDate = df.format(dateTime);
```

Comment: What type do you want to convert it to? Also unix timestamps are in full seconds

Comment: `ofEpochSecond` with the nanoAdjustment argument https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-long- would be your best bet

Comment: I know this is a duplicate of another recently active question involving the `E` notation in the number, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes of Java 8 and later. The `Date` class in incapable of representing the microseconds resolution of your input data.

I assume your number represents a number of whole seconds + fractional second since the epoch reference date of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z. We need to tear apart the count of whole seconds from the fractional second. We want the fractional second as a count of nanoseconds.

We use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for accuracy, as `double`/`Double` uses floating-point technology to trade away accuracy for performance.

```
String input = "1.514408397505346E9";
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( input );
BigDecimal microsDivisor = new BigDecimal( 1_000_000_000L );
long seconds = bd.longValue( );
BigDecimal bdMicros = bd.subtract( new BigDecimal( seconds ) ).multiply( microsDivisor );
long nanos = bdMicros.longValue( );
```

> input: 1.514408397505346E9
>
> bd: 1514408397.505346
>
> seconds: 1514408397
>
> nanos: 505346000

From that, instantiate an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( seconds , nanos ) ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-12-27T20:59:57.505346Z

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/vYLe4Q).

---

## ISO 8601

This use of `1.514408397505346E9` is a *terrible* way to represent date-time values. When serializing date-time values, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats only. In this case: `2017-12-27T20:59:57.505346Z`

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Date

```
Date currentTime = new Date(11111111111L);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dateString = formatter.format(currentTime);
```

And be careful, SimpleDateFormat is not threadsafe,

Comment: `Date` doesnt support micro seconds. Not sure what class the OP wants to use

Comment: @jontro The example value is milliseconds so I assume a mixup of terms

Comment: **Incorrect answer.** The input value apparently represents a date-time value in microseconds resolution. The troublesome old legacy date-time classes used here are limited to milliseconds. `1.514408397505346E9` = `1514408397.505346` = `2017-12-27T20:59:57.505346Z`